# HLOOKUP returns #N/A on last column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Data

[image]

Formula

[image]

I have a monster spreadsheet that I was adding columns to, I extended the HLOOKUP to include a 4th column "GEG" which returns N/A. The other 3 columns work without problems. I can only think this is an excel bug, but in case this was something anyone encountered I thought I'd ask. Note that if I replace the column names with A,B,C,D the 4th column works, so it's not like there's something invalid about the column. I also tried making the lookup value the literal column title with no luck. I also recreated the table and lookup with "GEG" as the 4th column without issue so there's nothing to do with that string.

Comment: I think you have to use the `FALSE` option. Without that `GEG` does not have a smallest match returning N/A

Comment: What is there at $AF$4? and where is the example you posted at $af$8?

Comment: FALSE worked, thank you. TRUE was only working before because they were in alphabetical order until I added GEG.

Comment: Try this: =HLOOKUP($AF$4,$AF$8:$AI$21,2,TRUE)